# css keyframe animation in firefox and IE

Tags: animation, css

http://dev.viral-minds.com/miller/abc/abc.html

two questions about this

1. How do I keep the green block from "blinking" at the beginning when the page loads?
2. The animation only works on chrome at the moment...how to get it to work in FF and IE?

thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>main</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body 
        {
            background-color:#FFFFF0; /*ivory*/
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #box
        {
            position: absolute;
            width:495px;
            height:263px;
            background:#32331d;
            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
        }

        #nav
        {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left:30px;
            width:100%;
            height:100px;
            top: 425px;
            z-index: 100;
            background-image:url('colors.png');
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }


        #stars,
        #stars-2,
        #small-stars,
        #small-stars-2 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            width: 800px;
            height: 800px;
            margin: -300px 0 0 -300px;
            background: url(stars-large.png) no-repeat center center;
            -webkit-animation-name: starsLarge;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 240s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes starsLarge {
            from {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(3);
                opacity: .9;
            }
            to {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(.5);
                opacity: .5;
            }
        }

        #stars-2 {
            -webkit-animation-name: starsLargeAlt;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 180s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes starsLargeAlt {
            from {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) scale(3);
                opacity: .9;
            }
            to {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(.5);
                opacity: .5;
            }
        }

        #small-stars,
        #small-stars-2 {
            background: url(stars-small.png) no-repeat center center;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
            -webkit-animation-name: starsSmall;
        }

        #small-stars-2 {
            -webkit-animation-name: starsSmallAlt;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 120s;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes starsSmall {
            from {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(3);
                opacity: .9;
            }
            to {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(.5);
                opacity: .5;
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes starsSmallAlt {
            from {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(3);
                opacity: .9;
            }
            to {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(.5);
                opacity: .5;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box"><img src="actual.png"></img></div>
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <div id="stars"></div>
    <div id="stars-2"></div>
    <div id="small-stars"></div>
    <div id="small-stars-2"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Item 1: The green block flickers because the overlayed image is not retrieved from the server yet.  You could add `display: none;` to the CSS for `#box`, then programmatically display it after the page has been fully loaded.  For example:

```
// jQuery:
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#box').show();
});
```

Item 2: The animation only works in Chrome because you are using `-webkit` specific style definitions.  You will need to research alternatives, such as `-moz` and `-ms` in order to see if it can work in those browsers.  You could also try omitting the prefix altogether.

Comment: Yes. You'll need to repeat the whole block with webkit replaced with moz, 0 and with nothing. IE10 doesn't use prefixes. Other IE doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

I. You can change the background color of that div to match the page background. And later, when the image has been loaded, you change it to dark green via jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#box img').load(function() {
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#32331D');
    });
});
```

II. You have to add browser specific prefixes other than `-webkit`.

- For FF - `-moz`
- For IE - `-ms`
- For Opera - `-o`

Just keep in mind that those animations won't work in older versions of IE (8 and under) despite the prefixes. Those suckers don't support CSS animations.